# How to write text in a box so that it only covers 50% of the box?

Tags: html, css

I have a box with 50% of it's background picture. Now I want to insert text in the rest 50% box so that the text doesn't overwrite the picture.

I will show you what I have done. Right now the text goes over the image. But I want the text right below the image.

HTML:

```
<p id="p_box1">Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
    <br/>Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
    <br/>Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
    <br/>Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
    <br/>
</p>
```

.CSS:

```
#p_box1 {
    padding: 18px 2%;
    border: 3px solid Crimson;
    float: left;
    /*
    width: 29.333333%;
    */
    width: 20.333333%;
    margin: auto 2%;
    margin-left:120px;
    border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -ms-border-radius:7px;
    -o-border-radius:7px;
    background:url("img_in/box_img_1.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 50%;
}
```

Comment: can't access the image. give us dimensions of that image or add the image here.

Comment: Two things: 1. Does this have to be a background image... is the image definitely **not** considered "content", is it purely presentational? 2. What's the reason to place this inside a paragraph element (`p`)?

Comment: misterManSam, it doesn't have to be a background image, but, however, the image should have border, as it does right now. And the text should go under the image with fitting inside the border (or box). Second,I don't know for the reason. I am a new learner. Probably it's not good practice to do so. That is, please help me to improve.

Comment: Can you add a link to the image? It will help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try by increasing the padding of p_box1 like
padding:50% 2% 0 2%;

which should buy you some padding space on top and it may increase the height of the box though, you can reduce the height according to your need, or wrap the text in another div or p and give it margin-top 50% or how much ever you need....
if you have a jsfiddle example or some live link, we can give clear solution...

Comment: padding top in percentage is respect to the **width** instead of **height**. so this will not work. In this case, `padding-top: 50vh` will work I think.

Comment: `vw` and `px`? definitely not.. I was thinking `vh` would but I am not able to solve here with it.

Comment: if could give a jsfiddl or live link, it will be easier., wrapping text in another element and giving it some margin-top might help out...

Comment: @BhavanKuchibhotla Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smenr5nq/3/) to work. (_added image_)

Comment: padding:50% 2% 18px 2%;
 seems to work, you can play around with 50% to your need...

Comment: @BhavanKuchibhotla not even close.. check by resizing the window. that is what I tried to explain you in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be not possible using just css. You should also consider javascript. To solve this, I wrapped a `div` to the content, made changes in css and added some code in javascript.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="p_box1">
    <div class="main">Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
        <br/>Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
        <br/>Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
        <br/>Text goes under the image . Text goes under the image
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#p_box1 {
    padding: 18px 2%;
    border: 3px solid Crimson;
    float: left;
    /*
    width: 29.333333%;
    */
    width: 20.333333%;
    /*original starts*/
    margin: auto 2%;
    /*original ends*/
    margin-left:120px;
    border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -ms-border-radius:7px;
    -o-border-radius:7px;
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 50%;
}
.main {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
var container = document.getElementById('p_box1');

function adjustImage() {
    var height = main.offsetHeight * 2 + "px";
    container.style.height = height;
}
adjustImage();

window.onresize = adjustImage;
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smenr5nq/8/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, i am sure it will solve. Last question: What if I have 6 similar boxes and do the same thing for each box. then in this javascript code: var container = document.getElementById('p_box1'); do i need to put the all id's for each box, then it will work?